# Remove all variables that have only 1 value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df :

```
>>>> df
        Genre  Rat View
Date                   
20111231  CNN  NaN HH  
20111231  CNN  210 HH  
20111231  NaN  4.3 HH
```

I need to clean DF to get a new one as example below:

```
          Rat
Date                   
20111231  NaN
20111231  210
20111231  4.3
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `apply` `pd.Series.nunique`, and then use that to select:

```
>>> df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
Genre    1
Rat      2
View     1
dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[:, ~(df.apply(pd.Series.nunique) == 1)]
            Rat
Date           
20111231    NaN
20111231  210.0
20111231    4.3
```